# deny acces namespace ability in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering how to deny access to a namespace on rails.
For example, I have a user model, where no administrator and a user. I have localhost:3000 path, which is accessed by all users, and localhost:3000/admin, where they can only be accessed by administrators. in the first route everyone can log in, but when go to the path /admin, only administrators should have access.
I have the user models, role.
my routes.rb

```
namespace :admin do
    resources :whatever
  end
```

ability.rb

```
if user.role.name == 'admin'
          can :access, :rails_admin
          can :manage, :all
else
    can :read, :all
end
```

I have my controllers of admin in a folder, it's other context.
Can I deny access to /admin to a non-admin user?
I'm using mongoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's more common to do that in controllers.

In my case, I use before_action in the AdminBaseController, which all admin related controllers inherited from, to validate if user is logged in as an admin.

```
class AdminBaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_admin_user!

  def authenticate_admin_user!
    # authentication related logic goes here
    redirect_to root_url unless current_user.try(:admin?)
  end
end
```